# In Powershell can you use the copy-item command to copy all the contents of a directory including folders?

Tags: powershell, backup, copy-item

I know how to do it with different commands but is there a way to make it so copy-item cmdlet also copies directories to the target folder for example if I wanted to copy everything in the C:\users folder including all directories and sub directories is it possible to do with the copy-item command.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with:

```
copy-item C:\users -recurse

copy-item C:\users -destination c:\somewhereelse -recurse
```

The first way assumes you are currently in the destination folder, the second way is explicit.

Comment: I suggest to use `-force` parameter if hidden or system files are present in source folder.